# A question on recursion -finding the parents of the taxon

Tags: python

I have  this dictionary:

```
tax_dict = {
    'Pan troglodytes': 'Hominoidea', 
    'Pongo abelii': 'Hominoidea',
    'Hominoidea': 'Simiiformes', 
    'Simiiformes': 'Haplorrhini',
    'Tarsius tarsier': 'Tarsiiformes', 
    'Haplorrhini': 'Primates',
    'Tarsiiformes': 'Haplorrhini', 
    'Loris tardigradus': 'Lorisidae',
    'Lorisidae': 'Strepsirrhini', 
    'Strepsirrhini': 'Primates',
    'Allocebus trichotis': 'Lemuriformes', 
    'Lemuriformes': 'Strepsirrhini',
    'Galago alleni': 'Lorisiformes', 
    'Lorisiformes': 'Strepsirrhini',
    'Galago moholi': ' Lorisiformes'
}
```

I have this code in python:

```
# print each step to follow up
def get_ancestors(taxon):
    print('calculating ancestors for ' + taxon)
    if taxon == 'Primates':
        print('taxon is Primates, returning an empty list')
        return []
    else:
        print('taxon is not Primates, looking up the parent')
        parent = tax_dict.get(taxon)
        print('the parent is ' + parent + ' ')
        print('looking up ancestors for ' + parent)
        parent_ancestors = get_ancestors(parent)
        print('parent ancestors are ' + str(parent_ancestors))
        result = [parent] + parent_ancestors
        print('about to return the result: ' + str(result))
    return result
```

when I run the function by:

```
get_ancestors('Galago alleni')
```

I get these results:

```
calculating ancestors for Galago alleni
taxon is not Primates, looking up the parent
the parent is Lorisiformes
looking up ancestors for Lorisiformes
calculating ancestors for Lorisiformes
taxon is not Primates, looking up the parent
the parent is Strepsirrhini
looking up ancestors for Strepsirrhini
calculating ancestors for Strepsirrhini
taxon is not Primates, looking up the parent
the parent is Primates
looking up ancestors for Primates
calculating ancestors for Primates
taxon is Primates, returning an empty list
parent ancestors are []
about to return the result: ['Primates']
parent ancestors are ['Primates']
about to return the result: ['Strepsirrhini', 'Primates']
parent ancestors are ['Strepsirrhini', 'Primates']
about to return the result: ['Lorisiformes', 'Strepsirrhini',
'Primates']
['Lorisiformes', 'Strepsirrhini', 'Primates']
```

Maybe this is a simple question, but I can not get that at all. I don't know how the result is a list of the parents. **I thought the result would be one value and it runs when the loop of recursion is done.**
I know its a basic recursion, Does anybody can help me with this? do you have any useful references that can help me with that? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your line -

```
result = [parent] + parent_ancestors
```

is essentially -

```
result = [parent] + get_ancestors(parent)
```

so at the highest level of recursion your building out the result by appending all the parents one by one based on the results returned from further down the recursion calls.

Answer (score 1):

If we cut out all of the printing, your function is basically equivalent to the following. I'm using `return` in conditionals to avoid excessive indentation.

```
>>> def get_ancestors(taxon, stop_on='Primates'):
...     if taxon == stop_on: return []
...     parent = tax_dict.get(taxon)
...     if not parent: return []
...     return [parent] + get_ancestors(parent, stop_on)
...
>>> get_ancestors('Galago alleni')
['Lorisiformes', 'Strepsirrhini', 'Primates']
>>> get_ancestors('Tarsius tarsier')
['Tarsiiformes', 'Haplorrhini', 'Primates']
```

Now, if you don't necessarily want a list, you *could* use `yield` to create a generator which generates parents on demand.

```
>>> def get_ancestors(taxon, stop_on='Primates'):
...     if taxon == stop_on: return
...     parent = tax_dict.get(taxon)
...     if not parent: return
...     yield parent
...     yield from get_ancestors(parent, stop_on)
...
>>> get_ancestors('Galago alleni')
<generator object get_ancestors at 0x7f7cecec06d0>
>>> list(get_ancestors('Galago alleni'))
['Lorisiformes', 'Strepsirrhini', 'Primates']
```